# How to choose interactions to test when there are many predictors?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, interaction

If I have many covariates $X_1, X_2, ... ,X_{15}$ in a linear regression model, how do I determine which two-way interactions to include?  Obviously there would be too many potential models to do a best subset regression. Should I fit all the two-way interactions and do a stepwise selection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way is by thinking about which interactions make sense, are interesting, are suggested by theory, etc.

Stepwise is not something I'd recommend. The whole "automated process" is something I wouldn't recommend - after all, if *two* way interactions should be explored this way, why not *three* way? Or *four*?

If you really have *no* theory to guide you, then this runs the risk of becoming a fishing expedition. But I think we often have more theory than we think we do! After all, you (or someone) picked these 15 variables for a reason.

Comment: Thanks. That was my initial plan. I just wasn't sure if I could just choose 'interesting' pairs of variables instead of going through all the different pairs.

Comment: The idea of what you "can" do in statistics is rather overblown, I think. It is well dealt with in the excellent book "Statistics as principled argument".